# Pass Azure service connection into variable in Team Services

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Visual Studio Team Services, I would like to specify the Azure Subscription via a variable (see image below). The reason for this is that our ops team maintains the NON-PROD and PROD environments on different subscriptions.

[image]

However, when I do this I get the following in the log:

```
##[section]Starting: Azure App Service Deploy: XXXXfunc
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure App Service Deploy
Description  : Update Azure App Service using Web Deploy / Kudu REST APIs
Version      : 2.1.10
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme)
==============================================================================
[RESOURCE_NAME] exists false
##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: CouldnotfetchacccesstokenforAzureStatusCode
##[error]CouldnotfetchacccesstokenforAzureStatusCode 401 Unauthorized
##[section]Finishing: Azure App Service Deploy: XXXXfunc
```

If I set the subscription using the drop down, then it all works fine.

Is this possible to do? If so, how?

UPDATE:

I am using App Service here as a simple example, but I also have a collection of Azure PowerShell tasks joined into a single Task Group. Each of these tasks need to have the subscription specified. If I can't pass a Azure sub in, then I'll have to either clone the Task Group or just list each step individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easier (and fits with how the system has been designed), if instead of this, you just use the Releases workflow to setup your dev/test environment, with the app service deploy pointing at that subscription, then clone that environment, call the new one "prod", and modify the release step in that environment to point at the other subscription.  You can then also add governance (ie. email approval processes) around the build and deploy, and ensure the exact same build artifact is deployed to both environments, but when you want them to.  I wrote a blog post last year to take you through this step by step, see https://russellyoung.net/2016/11/09/continuous-deployment-of-a-asp-net-core-app-to-azure-using-vsts/

Comment: My scenario is more complicated that just the App Service and I've updated my question. I am, however, using Releases.

Comment: Ah ok - but can't you do the same thing with the power shell task?  Or you pass in a subscription Id and use that as a param to your script?

Comment: Azure PowerShell scripts require the service connection. I could use a plain PowerShell script, but then I have to make sure the environment is correct and would need to use my credentials, instead of the service principal to make the calls. Essentially, make everything much harder than using the task that is set up for this. I can add a variable to the textbox/dropdown, so it would appear this is supposed to be supported in some way anyway.

Comment: I found that the Task Group exposes a drop down that works just as well as on the Azure PowerShell script itself. Variables still don't work, but this at least prevents me from duplicating my task group, so that's good enough.